# Querying an SQLite3 file on Ceph via s3a using Pyspark - requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection

Tags: sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, ceph

I feel I'm missing something trivial here, please help.

Solution is based on these articles:

Theory: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/why-spark-ceph-part-1-3
Implementation: https://radanalytics.io/examples/ceph-source-example

## Setup

I have set up a CEPH cluster on a remote server (server A) and copied over some sqlite3 files. I have also set up a Standalone Spark cluster on an another remote server (server B).

Due to company security policies (firewall etc.), I'm unable to run Spark jobs from my local machine directly, so I had to setup a remote development environment on a linux server (lets call it server C).

So I am able to run code from my local laptop using my IDE, where the code automatically syncs and executes on server C and sends the job to the Spark cluster (server B) which is querying the CEPH cluster on server A.

**And all of this WORKS JUST FINE for eg. txt, csv and similar files. **

## Problem

So to sum it all up:

I can query read regular files (txt, csv..) both via boto3 and with PySpark, but I can't seem to query an sqlite3 file which is stored on the Ceph cluster due to jdbc connection errors.

Makes me think that I'm missing something obvious here.

## Working Code Snippets

This is the simple boto3 example** which works**:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  endpoint_url='https://ceph-host.com',
                  aws_access_key_id='my_key',
                  aws_secret_access_key='my_access_key')

# list objects in bucket
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']

# print object names
for obj in objects:
    print(obj['Key'])
```

This is a simple PySpark job which reads a txt file, and **this also works**:

```
import pyspark
import os


# Ceph authentication
access_key = 'my_key'
secret_key = 'my_secret_key' 
ceph_host = 'http://ceph-host.com' 
ceph_port = 8000


# Creating a PySpark session
cwd = os.getcwd()

conf = pyspark.SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("1_main") \
    .setMaster("spark://master-host.com:port") \
    .set("spark.jars", "{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd, cwd)) \
    .set('spark.driver.extraClassPath', "{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd, cwd)) \
    .set('spark.executor.extraClassPath',"{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd,cwd))

spark = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)


# Adding the Ceph auth to Spark session
hadoopConf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "{}:{}".format(ceph_host, ceph_port))
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
hadoopConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")


# Querying a simple .txt file
url = str('s3a://bucketname/text.rtf')

l1 = spark.textFile(url).collect()

for row in l1:
    print(str(row))
    break
```

## Sqlite Code Snippet

Now to add on top of the previous example, I would just like to read an sqlite3 file and query it. If I use the same code as above and just replace the url with the sqlite3 file, it will start reading it as if it's text and print out a bunch of nonsense.

This is my Sqlite3 attempt:

```
import pyspark
import os


# Ceph authentication
access_key = 'my_key'
secret_key = 'my_secret_key' 
ceph_host = 'http://ceph-host.com' 
ceph_port = 8000


# Creating a PySpark session
cwd = os.getcwd()

conf = pyspark.SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("1_main") \
    .setMaster("spark://master-host.com:port") \
    .set("spark.jars", "{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd, cwd)) \
    .set('spark.driver.extraClassPath', "{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd, cwd)) \
    .set('spark.executor.extraClassPath',"{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd,cwd))

spark_session = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)


# Adding the Ceph auth to Spark session
hadoopConf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "{}:{}".format(ceph_host, ceph_port))
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
hadoopConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")


# Loading the Sqlite3 file
url = str('s3a://bucketname/filename.sqlite')
# alternative Url which also doesn't work:
# url = str('jdbc:sqlite:s3a://bucketname/filename.sqlite')

table_name = 'data'

df = spark_session.read.format("jdbc").options(url=url, dbtable=table_name, driver='org.sqlite.JDBC').load()

df.printSchema()
```

## Full error log

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection. Check the URL: s3a://bucketname/filename.sqlite
```

## Conclusion

Any tips on what I may be missing here? There aren't so many resources available online to point me to a solution, I've tried various other things, but this just seems trivial. I'd be grateful for any help whatsoever.